# Ionic controller dont show data on view on enter view

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have faced this problem when i enter on the view the jsonp function dont  atach the data to the list, when i refresh the ionic lab page the data is appended to the list.. bellow is the code of the service and the controller...thanks in adivice
function to enter the view

```
$state.go("app.meusPontos")
```

Controller

```
    .controller('meusPontosCtrl', function($scope, $http, $localStorage,$ionicLoading, $timeout, $ionicPopup,$state, MeusPontos,$stateParams,$window) {

MeusPontos.getPontos().success(function(response){
  $ionicLoading.show({

    content: 'Carregando Dados',
    animation: 'fade-in',
    showBackdrop: true,
    maxWidth: 200,
    showDelay: 0
});
           $timeout(function () {
            $ionicLoading.hide();
            console.log(response)
            $scope.pontos = response;                      

    }, 500);

}).error(function(response){
    console.log(response)
    alert("Erro ao Carregar Dados")
})
})

Service

    angular.module('app.services', [])
.factory('MeusPontos', function($http, $localStorage,$state) {
    return {
        getPontos: function(){
        return $http.jsonp('https://ssl-386475.uni5.net/bonus/ClienteIOS/MeusPontos?id='+$localStorage.user.Id)

        }


    }

})
```

Comment: when you go on the view the jsonp function, what do you see error in the developer console

Comment: the returnn of the response is undefined, when i reload the page the contents loads....

Comment: I thing you are using wrong localstorage.You can review http://jsfiddle.net/jgs4280c/